# Is there an open source font converter toolkit other than Font Forge?

Tags: open-source, font-utility

I'm looking for a simple GUI font conversion program. I've tried Font Forge but its GUI's clunky and crashes from time to time.

Requirements:

- Open source
- Windows (preferably)
- Convert write support for at least .eot, .svg and .woff
- GUI
- Stable

Comment: Which font types are you looking to convert from and to?